# TabBarItem image appears stretched

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have TabBarViewController in my application, and when I run the application on iOS 11, TabBarItem appears fine, but when I run it on iOS 10, the images are stretched.
Also when I select TabBarItem, the image getting smaller and bigger in very strange way.

Here's screen shot on how it appears on iOS 11
[image]

And here how it appears on iOS 10

[image]

What to do in this case?

Comment: What's your `contentMode` of your `UITabBar`?

Comment: @Ali omari have you added 2x 3x image in assets?

Comment: Try contentMode = aspect fit on the images of the tabbaritems

Comment: @kalpesh yes i add 2x and 3x images.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. also i tried with no hope.

Comment: @Tom it was Scale To Fill and i change it to Aspect Fit, nothing works

Answer (score 0):

It's because you probably set unbalanced imageInsets. (.top or .bottom alone)

Try to balance it like this:

```
item.imageInsets.top = 5
item.imageInsets.bottom = -5
```

Settings just one side works in iOS +11 but not below.